# Desk rejection from marketing journals

Tags: publications

I am curious as to how much time it takes to hear about desktop rejection from editors of Journal of Marketing, Journal of Marketing research, Journal of Consumer Research, Management Science etc. What does it mean if it says "awaiting COE decision"?

Comment: Your first question can only be answered by regulars, volunteers or employees of the journal (unless the journal published their times, in which case this will answer your question) and is thus too localised for this site. Also please note that we prefer to have one question per question. Anyway: Welcome to Academia SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"COE" most likely means Coeditor. I would expect that a decision about desk rejection is performed within 2 weeks or less from submission.